# Read questions and answers in an array and display

Tags: arrays, comparison

Comparing array elements and add 1 or 0 if the arrays are the same or not. But they are not adding up, where could i be doing it wrong? Because the arrays do not seem to be comparing.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Chosen answers</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>
<?php

//Posting of the chosen answers

$answers = $_POST['selected_answers'];
echo '<b><u>THE ANSWERS YOU HAVE CHOSEN ARE:</u></b><br /><br />';
print_r($answers);

//Opening of the answers file, reading and printing it

$openFile = fopen("answers.txt", "r") or exit ("unable to open the answers file");
$fileContents = fread($openFile, filesize("answers.txt"));
fclose($openFile);
$delimiter = "  ";
$myArray = explode($delimiter, $fileContents);

$score = $score1 = $score2 = $score3 = $score4 = $score5 = $score6 = $score7 = $score8 = 0;

//Computation of marks scored for the answered questions

if ($answers[0] == $myArray[0])
{
$score = 1;
}
elseif ($answers[0] !=$myArray[0])
{
$score = 0;
}echo '<br />';

if ($answers[1] == $myArray[1])
{
$score1 = 1;
}
elseif ($answers[1] !=$myArray[1])
{
$score1 = 0;
}echo '<br />';

if ($answers[2] == $myArray[2])
{
$score2 = 1;
}
elseif ($answers[2] !=$myArray[2])
{
$score2 = 0;
}echo '<br />';

if ($answers[3] == $myArray[3])
{
$score3 = 1;
}
elseif ($answers[3] !=$myArray[3])
{
$score3 = 0;
}echo '<br />';
if ($answers[4] == $myArray[4])
{
$score4 = 1;
}
elseif ($answers[4] !=$myArray[4])
{
$score4 = 0;
}echo '<br />';

if ($answers[5] == $myArray[5])
{
$score5 = 1;
}
elseif ($answers[5] !=$myArray[5])
{
$score5 = 0;
}echo '<br />';

if ($answers[6] == $myArray[6])
{
$score6 = 1;
}
elseif ($answers[6] !=$myArray[6])
{
$score6 = 0;
}echo '<br />';

if ($answers[7] == $myArray[7])
{
$score7 = 1;
}
elseif ($answers[7] !=$myArray[7])
{
$score7 = 0;
}echo '<br />';

if ($answers[8] == $myArray[8])
{
$score8 = 1;
}
elseif ($answers[8] !=$myArray[8])
{
$score8 = 0;
}

$Total = $score + $score1 + $score2 + $score3 + $score4 + $score5 + $score6 + $score7 +   $score8 ;

echo "<b><u>$Total</u></b>";
?>
</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I be able to compare the two arrays and compute the total marks. the first array       $answers is from a submitted form. and the second one is read from another text file called answers.txt

Comment: hey buddy read some basic concepts of conditional statement ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code is too redundant you should optimize it. try it

```
<?php 

$total=0;
if ($answers[1]=="Data coupling")
{
$total++;
}
else
{
print_r($answers[1]);
}

//third question
if ($answers[2]=="Unit testing")
{
$total++;
}
else
{
print_r($answers[2]);
}

//fourth question

if ($answers[3]=="Mutation testing")
{
$total++;
}
else
{
print_r($answers[3]);
}
//fifth question

if ($answers[4]=="white box testing")
{
$total++;
}
else
{
print_r($answers[4]);
}

//sixth question

if ($answers[5]=="Ad hoc")
{
$total++;
}
else
{
print_r($answers[5]);
}

//seventh question
if ($answers[6]=="information domain values")
{
$total++;
}
else
{
print_r($answers[6]);
}


//eigth question

if ($answers[7]=="Functional and behavioral")
{
$total++;
}
else
{
print_r($answers[7]);
}

//nineth question

if ($answers[8]=="Efficiency")
{
$total++;
}
else
{
print_r($answers[8]);
}

//code to generate the total score 

    echo $total;
?>
```

Comment: this is how i solved the problem. Thanks Chetan for assisting//Computation of marks scored for the answered questions
$score = 0;
$no_questions = 9;

for ($x = 0; $x < $no_questions; $x++) 
{
if ($answers_trimmed [$x]== $myArray_trimmed[$x])
    {
    $score++;
    }
}
echo '<br />';
echo "<b><u>$score</u></b>";